# Visual Studio Team Services Build with label not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

I have a label in my project
When I queue a build, and put the label in the "Source Version" field, prefixed with a L, it always comes up the following error:

```
    500: TF14064: Could not find label mylabel@$/.
```

Anyone been able to get this functionality to work?

Comment: For others hitting this thread, this same error can appear depending on the working directory.  i.e. A colleague recently had this issue running `path\to\tf.exe vc dir /version:LMyLabelName /recursive`.  The issue occurred because rather than being in the project's folder, the current working directory was a different project's (in fact, it was the directory used for our build scripts repo, rather than for the project being built's).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is that your label is not collection-scoped and therefore you need to provide a scope with your label.  If you created your label in Visual Studio, the scope is probably project-scoped.  So for example if your label is 'mylabel' and your project name is 'myproject' then in the Source Version field you should enter this:

Lmylabel@$/myproject

Here are a couple links that help explain labels and scopes if you are interested.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ew32kd1(v=vs.100).aspx
http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2008/03/label-scope-revealed.html

I'll update the Microsoft Connect Page with this information too.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue and have help you submit a feedback on Microsoft Connect Page, you can track the status here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2345698/500-tf14064-could-not-find-label-error-occurs-when-queue-a-build-with-specified-label

Comment: Thanks - looking forward to a resolution

Comment: We are investigating.  However, this is not an answer.  This should be a comment on the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for TFS build and the error says like: “Cannot find the current label tfs build”.

How to resolve the issue:

1. Go to Configuration of your TFS build
2. Make the Label sources as true
3. Build the solution now and it's building fine.

Please reach out if any issues.